# I have to display record of list of database with its creation date?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

`template1=# SELECT (pg_stat_file('base/'||oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification, datname FROM pg_database;`

```
       modification        |           datname           
---------------------------+-----------------------------
 2016-01-23 14:56:19+05:30 | template1
 2016-01-23 14:56:20+05:30 | template0
 2016-01-23 14:56:20+05:30 | postgres
 2016-09-05 10:00:55+05:30 | pos.odoo.local
 2016-09-06 19:01:40+05:30 | muda_live_20160815_18_15_00
 2016-09-28 18:25:03+05:30 | muda_backup_20160815
 2016-10-13 10:20:04+05:30 | bucaan_2016_10_13
 2016-10-13 19:06:23+05:30 | muda_live_2016_08_19
 2017-03-16 10:52:41+05:30 | test_v8
 2016-09-03 15:32:49+05:30 | odoo.local
 2016-09-03 15:49:00+05:30 | inventory.odoo.local
 2016-09-03 18:17:31+05:30 | client-a.odoo.local
 2016-09-03 18:42:15+05:30 | client-c.odoo.local
 2016-09-03 20:01:43+05:30 | client-e.odoo.local
 2016-03-21 18:36:22+05:30 | test_odoo_v8
 2016-04-04 15:32:04+05:30 | openerp7_test
 2016-06-03 11:19:57+05:30 | ozpool_3_6_2016
 2016-08-10 11:40:50+05:30 | test_odoo_v9
 2016-09-05 10:03:07+05:30 | client-g.odoo.local
 2017-03-16 10:38:59+05:30 | bol_ept
 2016-09-03 15:35:40+05:30 | s1.odoo.local
 2016-09-22 18:00:33+05:30 | lunch.odoo.local
 2016-09-03 18:28:19+05:30 | client-b.odoo.local
 2016-09-03 18:44:53+05:30 | client-d.odoo.local
```

(24 rows)

in this above list first 3 record is skip and only which record is display
before 15 days from current date, How i do ?

so, only 19 rows is display in output.

i want to print answer on console in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT
            (pg_stat_file('base/'||oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification,
            datname
         FROM pg_database
        ) dbs
WHERE datname NOT IN ('template1', 'template0', 'postgres')
   AND age(modification) > INTERVAL '15 days';
```

Answer (score 0):

## In .py file

```
@api.multi
def get_database_list(self):
    self._cr.execute("SELECT (pg_stat_file('base/'||oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification, datname FROM pg_database")
    temp = []
    res=self._cr.fetchall()
    dt=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(15)
    for i in res:
        dt1 = i[0].replace(tzinfo=None)
        if(dt1 < dt):
            result=self.env['ir.config_parameter'].search([('key','=','database.to.skip')])
            test=result.value.split(',')
            if i[1] not in test:
                temp.append((i[1]))
    print temp
```

## In .xml file

```
<record id="default_database_management" model="ir.config_parameter">
        <field name="key">database.to.skip</field>
        <field name="value">template1,template0,postgres</field> 
    </record>
```